# Populate MySQL table with db file

Tags: python, mysql

I have a xx.db file which I access with the keys, printing the keys to the screen for checking. There are many levels of keys, I'm showing the top level here.

```
    for filename in filenames:
        with contextlib.closing(shelve.open(filename, flag = "w")) as data:     
prdata = data['all'].keys()
```

print prdata
I have a table created like this in Python:

```
tbl= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
      `class` varchar(30) default NULL,
      `name` varchar(120) default NULL,
       )""" 
cursor.execute(tbl)
```

I would like to load the output of the first collection of data (from .db file) into the created MySQLdb table. How should I proceed?
Do I first need to create a text file from the db file?
I have read that LOAD DATA INFILE is a fast way to load data into the database from a text file. Since there is a lot of data in the db, it would be faster if I can skip making a text file first.

edit:
Have tried this, provides syntax error"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'prdata INTO TABLE table2 \n\t       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '' . 
I do not understand the syntax documentation correctly and also how to enclose it in Python.

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
```

> for filename in filenames:
>       with contextlib.closing(shelve.open(filename, flag = "w")) as data:
>           prdata = data['all'].keys()
>
> cursor.execute("""LOAD DATA INFILE prdata INTO TABLE table2 
>            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
>            """)

Update: Decided to go with INSERT INTO table2 (class,name) VALUE (%s,%s)
works fine

Answer (score 1):

When a connection is created, do not forget to add the local_infile parameter

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="appuser", passwd="",
db="test", local_infile = 1)
```

otherwise this error will appear:

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the loading from python as well:

```
cursor.executemany(
      """INSERT INTO table2 (class, name)
      VALUES (%s, %s)""",
      [
      ("class1", "name1" ),
      ("class2", "name2" ),
      ("class3", "name3" )
      ] )
```

docs http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: Sure, but the actual data resides in a .db file. So I was hoping to pull from that, rather than manually inserting the "class1","name1" etc.